# How to check if any item in a list of integers has a value greater than the length of the list

Tags: haskell

I am working on the n queens problem, my type signature is

```
queens :: [Int] -> Bool
```

The input is a list of row numbers of the queens. I am at a loss as to how to iterate through the list and compare each value to length xs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `any` function for this which will return `True` if at least one element in the list satisfies a given predicate (`Int -> Bool` function in this case).

```
queens xs = any (\x -> x > length xs) xs
```

Comment: An alternative: `or [ x > length xs | x <- xs ]`